# How to add UI components on top of tree view in VS Code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to build a tree view that has an always visible search field on just before a tree view in Visual Studio code. Ideally I want to have it look like a combination of those two:

[image: Visual Studio Code Test Explorer]

[image: Thunder Client]]

I understand that Thunder Client is built as a WebView which allows for all kinds of styling and content flexibility and that the built-in Test Explorer uses a native toolkit that does not seem to be accessible to extensions.

I already got the tree view working to 90% of what it should do and I'd really like to stick with using it. I know that I could add a search button to the title bar which would probably do the job. However, the tabs are pretty important for my case and I'd really display them in a prominent way. There does not seem to be a way to re-use the 'native' tree view inside a web view component..

I tried to use a web view on top of the tree view to provide the UI components using the VS Code UI Toolkit. However, this view is detached from the tree view and does not provide the UX i am trying to achieve as the panels can independently be placed.

Does anyone have an idea how I can add a header with a tab bar and / or a search field on top of it, so that those components are not resizeable as they would be if I implemented them as a separate web view?

Comment: use a `WebviewView`, then you have total control of all the GUI stuff

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! But how do I add the 'native' TreeView to the Webview?

Comment: you can't, you have to program everything yourself of use some kind of web framework

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to avoid. But it seems there is no other way.

Comment: I am dealing with potentially very large trees and I had to implement virtualization on my own.